# How to move Cloudwatch logs across regions?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm currently exploring an AWS setup using Lambda@Edge to capture metrics from viewer requests. Since I cannot control where the logs will end up (it simple ends up in Cloudwatch in the region closest to the request origin) I somehow need to transfer logs between regions.

I currently have an ElasticSearch cluster in eu-west-1 where I would ultimately want to ingest all my logs, from all regions. 
What is the recommended approach to move logs in CloudWatch from one region into and ElasticSearch cluster in another region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two options.

1. You can stream all of your log groups to lambda and have lambda post
   to ElasticSearch (repeat for every region).
2. You can stream your log groups to ElasticSearch as if it were in
   another account (repeat for every region). This would require a public endpoint for your ElasticSearch cluster.

Comment: Can you explain how to setup the streaming directly to ElasticSearch? When I click "Stream to ElasticSearch" on any loggroup except eu-west-1, the option "This account" is selected and it says "You don not have any Elasticsearch clusters in this region". Or I can select "Other account". But my ES cluster is not in another account...

Comment: It may not be in another account, but you need to treat it as if it were. When you select other account you can enter an ARN and endpoint (must be public).